# How to remove remove logo from sliding sidebar on wordpress theme on mobile

Tags: css, wordpress, web-deployment, mobile-website

I'm seeking some assistance with an issue I'm having in the development of a website for one of my clients. On desktop everything is fine however, on mobile devices the sliding sidebar/navigation has the logo that I would like removed. I've tried various solutions found through generic searches online to no avail.
The site I'm inquiring about is [Easter Seafood Enterprise Limited](https://easternseafoodenterprise.com). Is there any solution or CSS I can add to resolve this? P.S the logo on the page is fine and should remain it's only the logo in the sidebar (mobile devices) that I'd like removed.

Comment: In order to get assistance, it's best if you can include the relevant snippets of code that are controlling this logo and sidebar feature, as well as showing what you've already tried to solve the issue. Typically this site is for answering specific coding questions instead of troubleshooting something based on a link that might change/go away at any point. Instead of looking at the site, if we look at the code than this question would be useful for others in the future as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no way to remove the logo in the mobile navigation drawer for your theme via the Customizer or via Theme Options/Settings, then you can accomplish this with the following CSS:

```
.navbar-mobile .logo {
    display: none;
}
```

If you right click on your navbar and click inspect element, you should see that the class:

**"navbar-desktop"** `<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-desktop" data-mobile-screen-width="1200">` is being replaced with **"navbar-mobile"** at the 1200px breakpoint: `<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-mobile" data-mobile-screen-width="1200">`.

So you can use this **.navbar-mobile** class to target the mobile logo in the navigation drawer only by using the above CSS.

If you don't want to use CSS to accomplish this, another way is by copying the navbar.php file (or whichever file has the code to display the navbar) from your parent theme to your child theme and remove/comment out the line that adds the logo in the mobile navigation drawer.

Comment: This CSS snippet solved the issue and was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!